# Change ID of class back after .toggleClass() is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

```
jq(".1st").click(
  function() {   
      jq(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
      jq(this).toggleClass(this).attr("id","standfeat2");
  }
);
```

When I click on the drop button it drops down a message, then I want it to switch back to the original class "standfeat" when its clicked again. I swear I have tried everything and I know its something simple. I'm switching between 2 css id's.. One has a + and one has a - . Thanks for all the help in advance!

This is my CSS:

```
#standfeat {
    color:#185596; 
    font-size:24px; 
    padding-left:40px; 
    background: url(../images/standfeat.png) no-repeat 4px 50%; 
    line-height:24px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin:30px 0px; 
} 

#standfeat2 { 
    color:#185596; 
    font-size:24px; 
    padding-left:40px; 
    background: url(../images/standfeat2.png) no-repeat 4px 50%; 
    line-height:24px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin:30px 0px; 
} ​
```

Comment: `toggleClass(this)` is a problem.

Comment: Id's or classes. They are very different. `.toggleClass(this)` doesn't make any sense because `.toggleClass` expects a string, not an element. "css id" vs id attrute vs css classes, what are you referring to?

Comment: It changes the css from one to another. When it is clicked it switches and the css pulls a image as a -. But I just can't get it to switch back. Or if there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: This is my css..

#standfeat {
color:#185596;
font-size:24px;
padding-left:40px;
background: url(../images/standfeat.png) no-repeat 4px 50%;
line-height:24px;
cursor:pointer;
margin:30px 0px;
}
#standfeat2 {
color:#185596;
font-size:24px;
padding-left:40px;
background: url(../images/standfeat2.png) no-repeat 4px 50%;
line-height:24px;
cursor:pointer;
margin:30px 0px;
}

Comment: You should never have to programatically change the `id` of an element.

Comment: @Mac Edit the post, do not add additional code in comments!

Comment: @Mac: I edited your post, adding the css. `Eric:` Indeed that is correct. Changing the id programmatically can have all sorts of unwanted side effects. Not only does it possibly break any script which may be referring to the id of an element but also increases the risk of ending up with duplicate id values among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to modify the element id on click, it would be much cleaner to use classes for that purpose (which is why there is a `toggleClass` method but no `toggleId` method).

Modify your css to be:

```
.standfeat { color:#185596; font-size:24px; padding-left:40px; background: url(../images/standfeat.png) no-repeat 4px 50%; line-height:24px; cursor:pointer; margin:30px 0px; }
.standfeat2 { color:#185596; font-size:24px; padding-left:40px; background: url(../images/standfeat2.png) no-repeat 4px 50%; line-height:24px; cursor:pointer; margin:30px 0px; }
```

And then you can use the following jsL

```
jq(".1st").click(
    function() {   
        jq(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
        jq(this).toggleClass("standfeat standfeat2");
    }
);
```

[Working demo (not including your images)](http://jsfiddle.net/djE45/)

Comment: @David Actually, that works just fine, since the element will originally only have one of the classes when it is toggled that one will be turned off and the other will be turned on. The next time it is clicked, the classes are swapped again. Give it a try

Comment: OK, I hate to admit it but I was wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/aChgR/ however the logic is kind of awkward...

Comment: Yep, @nbrooks is right.  This is a great way to use `toggleClass()`

Comment: @david It seems fairly intuitive and is really the cleanest way to alternate between two classes. It's a simple bit flip: one off and one on, flip both each time -- you will always have exactly one on and exactly one off. It's certainly the least repetitive syntax, anyway :)

Comment: @nbrooks , I am going to try this, but I have a question. If my id in my javascript is ".1st" can I have another id .standfeat in my css and call two id's?

Comment: @mac An element can only have a single, unique Id. You can however have multiple values for class, separated by spaces. e.g. `<button class="1st standfeat" ></button` (note technically a valid class name wouldn't actually start with a number, but that shouldn't break anything...). See the html in my demo.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean classes, not IDs. `toggleClass` does not toggle between two classes, it either adds or removes a class, f.ex:

```
jq(this).toggleClass('open');
```

First time this function is called, it adds the class `open`. Next time it removes it, etc. You can use that logic in your CSS to style the different states, f.ex:

```
li{ background: url('plus.png') no-repeat; }
li.open{ background-image: url('minus.png'); }
```

If you *really* want to toggle IDs, you could do something like:

```
this.id = this.id == 'standfeat' ? 'standfeat2' : 'standfeat';
```

Comment: The last suggestion worked exactly how I wanted it to! Thank you. Sorry, I had a hard time explaining it. Next time if I write the code I won't switch between id's. Thank you again.!!

Comment: @Mac: Change your CSS to be referring to classes not referring to ids and switch out classes instead. What you doing right now is utter bad practice and most likely end up in a future issue due to some unexpected side-effects.

Comment: `toggleClass()` can toggle between classes... kinda.
`jq(this).toggleClass('standfeat standfeat2');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a class name to `toggleClass()`, not a reference to an `object`.

```
jq(".1st").click(
  function() {   
      jq(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
      jq(this).toggleClass("someClassName").attr("id","standfeat2");
  }
);
```